# Как работать с gui из Async потока?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность, async-await

Как работать с gui из Async? Ну вот например : есть progressbar и есть button у которого на событии `Async onclick` лежит следующий код `Await Task.Run((){progressbar.value = 77})` и он конечно же "вылетает", так вот, что мне делать?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам `Task.Run`, а не просто async-обработчик. Покажите весь код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант — если вы уж находитесь в async-функции, то не вызывайте `Task.Run` раньше времени. Например, вы можете сделать как-то так:

```
async void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.IsEnabled = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // выгружаем в фоновый поток ту операцию, которая должна быть асинхронной
        bool isGood = await Task.Run(() => ComputePart(i));
        // остаток кода продолжает бежать в UI-потоке
        if (isGood)
            progressBar.Value = i;
    }
    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Ещё три варианта описаны в отличном ответе @Lightness.

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант можно использовать [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).
Пример:

```
private async void ChangeProgressBar()
    {
        var uiSync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            uiSync.Send(state =>
            {
                progressbar.value = 77
            }, null);
        });
    }
```

---

Также можно использовать [Progress< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Пример:

```
    private async void ChangeProgressBar()
    {
        IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(value => { progressBar.Value = value; });

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                progress.Report(i);
                await Task.Delay(20);
            }
        });
    }
```

---

Еще один вариант это использование [Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591593(v=vs.110).aspx). Пример:

```
private async void ChangeProgressBar()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            progressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value = 77, DispatcherPriority.Background);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ну и Invoke то добавьте для проформы)

Comment: @Alexis, Готово :)

Comment: Вариант с прогрессом остроумный, да.

Comment: @VladD, Я что-то неверно написал? :)

Comment: @Lightness: Нет, что вы, я без всякой задней мысли. Все три варианта отличные. У вас мой +1.

Comment: @VladD, Понял, спасибо :)